# When appears Reply/Quote/Ack/Done buttons?

Tags: gerrit

When appears Reply/Quote/Ack/Done buttons? What means button "fix" and who marks "resolved"? I can't find any information. I have information about comment, but only reply/done/qoute

Comment: I didn't find the "fix" button (Gerrit 2.16.7), where is it? I didn't understand what is your question about Reply/Quote/Ack/Done buttons.

Comment: I think the "Fix" button only appears for "robot comments".